# RANKX in table and slicers

Tags: powerbi, dax

This is table Fact:

```
Date        Person Place Status Sales

01/01/2020  ABC North   Active  9852
14/01/2020  DEF North   Active  3452
17/01/2020  GHI North   Active  9084
02/02/2020  GHI North   Active  4902
14/02/2020  GHI North   Active  4659
14/02/2020  DEF South   Inactive    5000
23/02/2020  GHI North   Active  1685
10/03/2020  GHI North   Active  6401
21/03/2020  ABC Center  Active  4742
09/04/2020  ABC Center  Active  6325
14/04/2020  ABC Center  Active  8329
27/04/2020  ABC Center  Inactive    7740
28/04/2020  ABC Center  Inactive    5091
02/05/2020  ABC Center  Inactive    3763
04/05/2020  ABC Center  Inactive    1434
06/05/2020  DEF Center  Active  3718
22/05/2020  DEF South   Active  6639
03/06/2020  DEF South   Active  5672
12/06/2020  DEF South   Active  5268
16/06/2020  DEF South   Active  3358
```

I want to calculate the ranking of sales, depending on slicers for dimensions date, person, status and place.

So:

This measure:

```
TotalSales = SUM('Fact'[Sales])
```

Gives me the to total sales.

And:

This measure:

```
Ranking =
IF([TotalSales],
RANKX (
ALLSELECTED ('Fact'),
CALCULATE ( [TotalSales] ),
,
DESC,
DENSE
))
```

Is supposed to give me the ranking.

And it does, if all the dimensions are in:

[image]

However, if I remove the date:

[image]

This is non-sense. Can anyone help calculating the rank? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I'm replacing my answer completely because I misunderstood your problem.

I used the following:

```
Rank1 = 
CALCULATE(
    RANKX(
        ALLSELECTED(Table1[Person], Table1[Place], Table1[Status]), 
        CALCULATE(
            SUM(Table1[Sales])
        )
    )
)
```

Using your data, I made the visuals below, and am able to slice by place, person, and status. The problem with slicing by date, however, is that it's too granular, so that everything becomes #1 within that date period. You may want to add new columns like "Year" or "Quarter" which you can then add to the ALLSELECTED() statement in order to rank by, say, the person's best quarter, or the area's best year.

[image: Slicing by dimension]

[image: Slicing by date is too granular, giving multiple rank values]

Comment: @NunoNogueira I updated my attempt to solve your problem. I think that if you want to slice by date, you'll need to create separate dimensions for Year, Quarter, etc. so that you can include them in the ALLSELECTED() statement.

Comment: Hi, pls see my edit with the pbix link. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you got it, let me check back again tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

I opened your file & have some good news. I was able to find the issue.

**STEP 1**
Select all the **Months** & **Places** in your filters in the top. Hold `CTRL` to select multiple items. On the right, get rid of all the things that are in the way. Just check what I show here.

[image]

**STEP2**
`Un-check` the **Date** to see that the report goes crazy.

[image]

**STEP 3**
`Un-check` **Total Sales** & `check` **Sales** instead. You can also `re-check` **Date** here.

[image]

**STEP 4**
Hit the drop-down menu for **Sales** & select `Don't Summarize`.

[image]

**STEP 5**
Enjoy that you now have all 20 records again, but with **no Date** showing.

[image]

Comment: Hi, pls see my edit with the pbix link. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @NunoNogueira - I got your report & was able to fix it. Please re-read my answer as I have completely changed it based on your actual pbix file.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to aggregate the sales (as a sum) and to have the ranking.

Comment: Your original question was based off a table called "Fact" and I solved it. Then the question evolved to review your file & I solved it again. Now the requirements evolve again. Sorry, but I don't see an end to this rabbit hole. Good luck with your issue.